# How to use MongoDB as Dataware house database

Tags: mongodb, data-warehouse

I am  on design phase of   Business Intelligence application  and its deals with large volume of data. I have short listed "MONGO DB" as  back end.

But not able to find any data modeling notes  for Mongodb as Data ware house.How we define DIM  and FACT related modeling in Mongodb

Comment: This [**thread**](http://www.quora.com/Can-MongoDB-be-a-good-solution-for-a-data-warehouse-for-BI-If-yes-which-BI-visualisation-vendors-support-MongoDB-correctly) should give you an insight else this question could be considered as broad.

Comment: Don't. Just don't. Mongo is a document database. It is not for relationships. A regular SMP RDBMS can handle billions of rows (and terabytes of data) just fine. A MPP one can handle petabytes.